# В edit нужно рисовать таблицу

Tags: c++, qt, table, qtextedit

Мне нужно в окне  рисовать  таблицу в qt
Я делаю так:
    Создаю таблицу:

```
QTableView* tableView = new QTableView();
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(3,3, tableView);
tableView->setModel(model);

for(int row=0; row!=model->rowCount(); ++row)
{
    for(int column=0; column!=model->columnCount(); ++column)
    {
        QStandardItem* newItem = new QStandardItem(tr("%1").arg((row+1)*(column+1)));
        model-> setItem(row, column, newItem);
    }
}
```

Создаю едит и пердаю туда наблицу:

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit;
textEdit->setPlainText(tableView);
textEdit->setFixedSize(790, 620);
textEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
```

Но ничего не рисуется. Подскажите как правильно нарисовать таблицу с 3 на 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так не работает.

Для установки текста у `QTextEdit` есть методы [setPlainText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText), [setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop) и объединяющий оба метода [setText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setText). Эти методы принимают строку.

Если вы хотите добавить таблицу в `QTextEdit`, вы можете ее составить в виде HTML таблицы и передать ее в метод [setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop).

Например:

```
textEdit->setHtml("<table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>");
```

---

Т.е. вам нужно будет пройтись по ячейкам `QTableView` (или `QStandardItemModel`),
и составить строку HTML, в которой будет таблица, после эту строку вставить в `textEdit` через [setHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#html-prop).

Алгоритм:

```
QString html = "<table border='1' style='border-style:solid' cellspacing='-1' cellpadding='5'>";

for (int row = 0; row < model->rowCount(); ++row) {
    html += "<tr>";

    for (int column = 0; column < model->columnCount(); ++column) {
        QStandardItem* item = model->item(row, column);
        html += "<td>" + item->text() + "</td>";
    }

    html += "</tr>";
}

html += "</table>";

textEdit->setHtml(html);
```

Вот так будет выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** есть и другой способ добавления – через текстовый курсор и [QTextTableFormat](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtexttableformat.html) / [QTextTable](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtexttable.html#details).

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/master/FormattingToolbar/FormattingToolbar.cpp#L623)

```
QTextTableFormat textTableFormat;
// Сделаем столбцы одинаковой ширины и их размер будет зависеть от размера
// текстового поля
QVector < QTextLength > lenghts;
for ( int column = 0; column < cols; column++ )
    lenghts << QTextLength( QTextLength::PercentageLength, 100.0 / cols );
textTableFormat.setColumnWidthConstraints( lenghts );

editor->textCursor().insertTable( rows, cols, textTableFormat );
```

Comment: спасибо, а как сделать чтобы  линий  между ячеек не  было видно? или минимальные линии сделать

Comment: Это вопрос уже к html/css :) Создаете <head> в нем <style>, а там уже играетесь с стилями :) т.е. у вас там будет "<html><head><style>...<style><body><table>...</table><body><html>". Либо можно в таблицу добавить атрибут `style`. Вот пример добавления рисования границы ячеек: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/webserver__handler_key_mouse_click/templates/index.html#L87 Если вам ответ понравился, [то отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: а как над ячейками названия написать? у меня 3  названия   но они один около одного а мне нужно чтобы  писалися над ячейкой https://c.radikal.ru/c40/1807/de/a1da3aab5560.png

Comment: `<tr><th>столбец1</th><th>столбец2</th><th>столбец3</th></tr>`?

Comment: так? <tr><th>"Названия"</th><th>"Тип"</th><th>"Дата"</th></tr>; но оно ошибки выдает

Comment: я делала через QTextTableFormat / QTextTable.

Comment: я  так  писала:  textEdit->textCursor().insertText("Названия");
    textEdit->textCursor().insertText("Тип");
    textEdit->textCursor().insertText("Дата");

Comment: Тут я вам не помогу, да и считаю что лучше через html сделать

Comment: а как  пройтись по ячейкам QTableView (или QStandardItemModel), и составить строку HTML, в которой будет таблица, после эту строку вставить в textEdit через setHtml? У меня  не вішло. можете пример скинуть. если не сложно

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос по этой проблеме и напишите сюда ссылку на него )

Comment: так  мой вопрос относится к этой теме.  зачем  другую создавать?!

Comment: `Подскажите как правильно нарисовать таблицу с 3 на 3` я подсказал, разве нет? :)

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, разобрался. Проблема была в том, что css не поддерживается рендером qtextedit/qtextdocument, поэтому настраивать отображение нужно через атрибуты

Comment: спасибо огромное. я  не  знаю как тут  еще +1 поставить)

Comment: @OxanaVolynets, а я ведь предлагал новый вопрос задать ))

Comment: Можете показать как вы задаете размеры таблицы, размеры ячейки, выравнивания текста. На html в qt.

Comment: @zhilenkov, вопрос точно к qt, а не r html? Размеры таблицы: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_sizes.asp Размеры ячеек: http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/width Выравнивание текста: http://htmlbook.ru/html/td/align

Comment: А вы пробовали создавать документ .odt с таблицей сделанной на HTML?

Comment: @zhilenkov, неа

Comment: Сможете дать пример для qt на html 2 горизонтально расположенные таблицы.

Comment: @zhilenkov, не, создайте отдельный вопрос, добавьте туда попытку решения, чтобы вопрос не попробовали закрыть. А так, наверное, тут понадобится табличная верстка (таблица без рамки с 1 строкой и двумя ячейками, в которых будут те 2 таблицы)